# Do dog silencers really work?

Tags: dogs, training, vocalizations

For the problem of dog barking, there is a device called a dog silencer, for example [this one here](https://www.electric-collars.eu/anti-barking-units/dogsilencer-max-bark-control-goodlife?gclid=CjwKCAjw8ZKmBhArEiwAspcJ7mD-sXBMzlJU4xZNp9QT3tb-Cq4T_9d5vn2u3KIhAZozy8h-J1T2KBoCp4UQAvD_BwE). Does anybody know if these kinds of device really work? My dog barks all the time, making me and my neighbors crazy. Nights, days, inside car, etc., my dog barks when he sees or hears a dog, cat, stranger, etc.